# how to compare tables in different database using java arraylist

Tags: java, database, arraylist

I have stored records in two arraylist from tables from two databases.Now I want to compare these two arraylists.If there is not matching then insert records from table1 to table2.

Comment: First: Show your code. Second: What should be compared? You have to be way more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code which might help you.

```
java.util.ArrayList al1 = [Your first array list retrieval method from first table];
java.util.ArrayList al2 = [Your second array list retrieval method from second table];
//Use iterator to go through each element of al1
java.util.Iterator iter1 = al1.iterator();
while(iter1.hasNext()){
     //I assume strings are there in your array list
     java.lang.String currentElement = iter1.next();
     if (!al2.contains(currentElement)){
          //Your code to insert into second table
     }
}
```

Comment: thank u so much for ur help Mr;ravindra gulllapalli  I have one more doubt continuation of my first ques? query for how to insert entire row when we mention a particular columvalue(rowid) in which row id i have set as primarykey i have compare and findout which is not present in table2 so i want to insert entire row by using this rowid is it possible or any other method ,if it is possible how? thnks in advnce

Comment: That is simple. You store row ids in array lists and inside if condition above, you can write code to insert that record of the first table into second table.